# NTLM Authentication Browserstack C#

Tags: c#, selenium, authentication, proxy, ntlm

I am currently trying to Authenticate and pass my NTLM proxy. I am using C# and Selenium trying to connect to

> hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub/

For automation purposes.

Would you guys have any solutions for the NTLM Authentication using selenium ?

btw the authentication has to occur in the header. As there's no windows popup